# How to add post process volume script in unity 2019?

Tags: unity

i have old unity 2018 project and imported standard character asset. The 3d player has this script : **post process volume** and **post process layer**. In 2018 i can add this component but not in 2019 . This component is not available in 2019. What is the replacement for this ? or how to achieve the same result for 2019 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [Post-Processing package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@2.3/manual/index.html) from the Unity Package Manager.